# Convert Object to array of Bytes

Tags: c#, client-server

I have a server which communicates with Clients using a `TCP` Sockets .

I want to send an object from one of the client `(Sender)` to server which sends this object to another client `(Receiver )`

the object contains fields of different types like this

```
Class Test {
      public string key;
      public int id;
      public string message;
      public Test ()
      {
         // constructor code
      }

}
```

my question is how to convert the object to array of bytes, and when receive this array of bytes in `Receiver` how to do the opposite operation (convert from array of bytes to objects)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [serialize your object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx). There are plenty of ways of doing that in C#.

You can serialize your object to binary bytes, XML or custom forms. If you want binary bytes (apparently that's what you're looking for) you can use [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

From the MSDN example:

```
Test test = new Test();
FileStream fs = new FileStream("output", FileMode.Create);
// Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
try 
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, test); 
}
catch (SerializationException e) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
    throw;
}
finally 
{
    fs.Close();
}
```

Of course, instead of a `FileStream` object you will use a socket output stream to send data.

If you are considering multiple platforms, I would suggest you use an XML based serialization so you won't run into issues related to platform endianness (byte order).